# Unity C# Wait then do

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm working through Unity's Space Shooter course and I've gotten to the point where I have Asteroids coming at me and I can destroy them.

When an asteroid detects a trigger collision it triggers the "showExplosion" method. The problem is, after we destroy the game object and instantiate the explosion, the explosion still remains as an object.

This is obviously a bad practice.

What I need to do (I think) is wait for that animation to complete and then destroy the object.

Now I assume there is an event that I can listen for... Which would be nice to know as well..

But how do I simply say Wait for X seconds and then destroy the explosion object.

Comment: `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  if (other.tag == "Boundry" || other.tag == "Player") {
   return;
  }
  Destroy (other.gameObject);
  Destroy (gameObject);
  GameObject exp = Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
  StartCoroutine (DestroyObjectAfterSeconds(exp,1));
 }

 IEnumerator DestroyObjectAfterSeconds(Object objectToDestroy, float waitTime)
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
  Destroy (objectToDestroy);
 }`

Comment: The above does not work

Comment: This is working for me check you will be making any other mistake.

Answer (score 2):

By using Coroutines you can do something like this.

```
IEnumerator DestroyObjectAfterSeconds()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeInSeconds);
   //DestroyObject here
}
```

in your showExplosion method call

```
 StartCoroutine("DestroyObjectAfterSeconds");
```

If you want to wait for animation to complete and then destroy game object you can add an event to your destroy animation in unity. For this click on your game object having destroy animation and then go to window at topbar or press command + 6 and open animation window now you select your last frame of animation and you can add an event to last frame of your animation. And this way you can destroy your game object when your animation is completed. :)

Comment: This is not working for me.. I may be wrong but if you return before you do something, won't it not do the stuff below?

Comment: This is not working for me.. I may be wrong but if you return before you do something, won't it not do the stuff below?

Comment: its not the simple return its yield return.. when you call the StartCoroutine("DestroyObjectAfterSeconds") it will execute any code written above yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeInSeconds); statement and then return and wait for seconds and then come back to this function and execute statements written after yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeInSeconds); that is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to do this, but the simplest one is to use the second parameter in **Destroy**, which is time to destroy.

For example `Destroy(myGameObject,5F);` will destroy the game object after 5 seconds.

So, in the asteroid script, in the moment you instantiate the explosion, call `Destroy(explosionObject,10F);` (give enough time for explosion to finish, it doesn't matter if stays in scene a little longer)

I think it should work properly, if not, you could use an independent script in explosion, which calls `Destroy(this.gameobject,10F)` in Start() method

If you want a Wait then do more generic (not only for Destroy) you could use [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: 5f what does this mean. I assume 5 frames?

Comment: It is time in seconds 5f means 5 seconds f is used for float.